# I'm sending an amount on a contract call but the contract is not seeming to recognize the amount

Tags: transactions, taquito, wallets, operation, tezos-signer

I'm trying to make a contract call that requires an amount of tezos to be sent in. I've done this before and it has worked, but now I get this error every time.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
  const costOfNFT = 0.1

  const value = { amount: costOfNFT }

  const purchaseNFTOperation = await contract.methods
     .buy(nftId)
     .send(value)
```

Here's the error:

```
[amount] Value is not a number: undefined
undefined
NatValidationError
NatToken {
  val: { prim: 'nat', annots: [ '%amount' ] },
  idx: 1,
  fac: [Function: createToken],
  createToken: [Function: createToken]
}
```

It seems like somehow it's not recognizing the amount I'm sending. I've tried as well:

```
  const value = { amount: costOfNFT*1000000, mutez:true }
```

Let me know if there's another way to send tezos in a contract call. I'm super confused how this works in another contract call I'm doing.

Thanks

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it looks like you may be trying to call an entrypoint that expects a value of type `nat` called `amount`. Could you share the entrypoint type signature in Michelson?

Comment: @ClaudeBarde You are exactly correct! I got thrown off because I was alternating between two contracts which I thought were identical, but one of them had another param called "amount". This was thrown when trying to call that contract & not the other. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was all because I was trying to call a contract with a param called "amount" that I was not passing. I got thrown off because I was alternating between two contracts which I thought were identical, but one of them had another param called "amount". This was thrown when trying to call that contract & not the other. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

1000000 mutez is 1 tez, so give this a try instead?

`const value = { amount: costOfNFT * 1000000, mutez:true }`

Hope it helps:)